# How to manipulate data and display it through Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, data-manipulation

**Background**

I have created an small app that can add projects, and show it in the index page, all those projects can be access individualy to its own "profile proJect page" clicking on the project name.

Inside the project's profile page, it can be seeing data as ProjectName, ResponsableName, Description and all related data per page.

**Problem**

Now that have the app, I would like manipulate the data from the django models and display the analysis into another HTML page, is there any library you could recommend or it is posible to do it only with Django ? Where should I start ? I'm available to response any upcomming questions.

Comment: You can manipulate the data in your views and then render to html

Comment: It is posible for example make mathematics operations through Django views?

Comment: Yes, anything you can do with python or related libraries